# sweetalert is not working if i unset the session

Tags: php, session, sweetalert

I have a session named success and I am doing if the session is isset then show a sweetalert and it's working properly before i unset the session

```
<?php 

if(isset($_SESSION['success'])){
    // unset($_SESSION['success']);
    ?>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        swal({
          title: "Thank You!",
          text: "Our Volunteer Will Contact You Soon!",
          icon: "success",
          button: "Close!",
        });
    </script>
    <?php 
}
?>
```

If i remove the comment on unset then alert is not coming

Comment: Try to add it in onload methold and add this src script outside this condition

Comment: but i want alert only if the condition is true

Comment: are you getting any error in your console like swal is not a function

Comment: no i am not getting any error

Comment: I think the issue is in that page is not able to reload when session get set

Comment: but if I don't use unset then alert is working properly

Comment: if its working, then you should unset session when user click on close button

Answer (score 0):

When you are redirecting to the page where you want to show the SweetAlert then use `exit(0)` after the header redirect.

```
header("Location: $self");
exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work i hope it works on you too

Make a php file and this is the content

**script.php** content:

```
 <script>
    swal({
      title: "Thank You!",
      text: "Our Volunteer Will Contact You Soon!",
      icon: "success",
      button: "Close!",
    });
</script>
```

Then do it like this

```
    <?php 

if(isset($_SESSION['success'])){
    ?>
            <?php include('script.php'); ?>
    <?php
   unset($_SESSION['success']); 
}
?>
```

This is my first answer on any question i hope it helps :)